# Como fazer com que uma UL fique centralizada horizontalmente e verticalmente numa nav?

Tags: html, css

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
nav{ width: 100%; height: 100px; background:gy;margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);}
nav ul{list-style: none; }
nav ul li {display: inline;padding: 5px; padding-top: 50px;}
nav ul li a {text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px; color: white;margin-top: 50px}
nav ul li:hover {background: rgb(18, 155, 219); transition: 1s linear}


body{background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0517Im379dI/maxresdefault.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
   
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Inicio<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contatos<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">produtos<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portifólio<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre Nós<a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: O seu `padding-top` na LI não funcionou pq vc colocou `display:inline` nela. Se vc quiser alinhar com padding como vc tentou basta colocar `nav ul li {display: inline-block;.....` ai seu `padding-top` vai começar a "fazer efeito".

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda

Comment: Disponha, e mesmo vc já tendo resolvido o problema ai, tira uma meia horinha para ler a resposta que marquei como duplicada. Ela já vai te ajudar a resolver metade dos problemas de alinhamento que vc vai ter no futuro! []´s

Comment: Como eu fecho a pergunta?

Comment: Não se preocupe com isso, deixa que agora ela vai ser *clickbait* para as buscas orgânicas rss. Mas se quiser mesmo excluir tem um link de `remover` na sua pergunta, é só clicar nele...

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é disso que precisa:

```css
*{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background:gy;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul li {display: inline;padding: 5px; padding-top: 50px;}
nav ul li a {text-decoration: none; font-size: 20px; color: white;margin-top: 50px}
nav ul li:hover {background: rgb(18, 155, 219); transition: 1s linear}


body{
    background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/0517Im379dI/maxresdefault.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
   
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Inicio<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contatos<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">produtos<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portifólio<a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sobre Nós<a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Leitura recomendada: [CSS-Tricks - A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: muito obrigada pela sua ajuda